# Cannot access localhost on browser

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, ssl-certificate

I have just recently installed XAMPP on another MacBoor Air. However, I am encountering an issue where I cannot access the localhost on my Chrome browser. These are the following errors I get from the browser. Could anyone advice how to solve this issue?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You somewhen had a `localhost` `SSL-Certificate`. With a `301`. The `redirects` are hard `cached`. Try to delete all `cached`.

Comment: you may want to try mamp

Comment: your connecting to a https protocol without a valid ssl-certificate

Comment: You can install a local ssl certificate if you really need one, otherwise just use `http://localhost` instead of `https://localhost`

Comment: @AjAX. I deleted all cache, but still did not work

Comment: @RaymondNijland how do I add a valid ssl-certificate?

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou I tried both http://localhost and https://localhost. However, I still get the same error message from my browser

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/288002. Look at the comment by Jason  S.

Comment: Did you try to run the localhost server on another port? Since on xampp, Skype sometimes messes with porth 80. This might be the issue here too.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema I do not have skype on my computer.

Comment: @ApplePie I used skype as an example, there might be another program on your computer, messing with the port?

Comment: Which browser is that? And are you using an anti-virus? I once had problems with Firefox and avast and all my connections were flagged insecure

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao I have managed to solve this problem with Firefox browser which allows me to add exception to the localhost access. It seems that Safari and Chrome are blocking insecure connections on my Laptop